# GetOpenFileName VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I specify a directory when adding files on excel worksheets using VBA by clicking on a button?
I have the below code that I've written to add files but I want to specify to the user that the file is in some directory, for example, C:\Users\sal\Desktop\Work\Files\Doc
so when he adds a file he will be directed to a folder named "Doc" where he can add the file he wants.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    repertoire = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ChDir

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ChDir "C:\Users\sal\Desktop\Work\Files\Doc"
    repertoire = Application.GetOpenFilename()

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I used the code you suggested but Nothing has changed